# How to dynamically include controller from string for directives?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I need to dynamically choose the controller at ngRepeat based on component name as a string. Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/osLLf0c4eNCpNokyyXCI?p=preview

As you can see I found a solution, but I don't think this is an Angular way, because I've created a stack of controllers and assign them to "controllers" variable outside the angular scope.

Here is HTML:

```
<table border="1" class="item" data-ng-repeat="component in components">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div component="component"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module("sortableApp", []);
app.controller("appCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.components = [{
        name: 'simpleText',
        tpl: 'simple-text.html',
        content: 'Simple text'
    }, {
        name: 'heading',
        tpl: 'heading.html',
        content: 'Heading'
    }];
}]);
app.directive("component", ["$templateCache", "$compile", function($templateCache, $compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            component: "="
        },
        controller: function($scope) {
            if(controllers[$scope.component.name]) {
                return controllers[$scope.component.name]($scope);
            }
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {},
        template: '<div ng-include="component.tpl"></div>'
    }
}]);

var controllers = {
    simpleText: function($scope) {
        $scope.add = function() {
            alert('add text');
        }
    },
    heading: function($scope) {
        $scope.add = function() {
            alert('add heading');
        }
    }
}
```

How to achieve my goal in angular way? thanks for your answer!

Comment: referenced fiddle is purely based in angularjs.

Comment: So, the controller definition outside the angular module is a normal way?
I saw following construction
`
    controller : "@",
    name:"controllerName",
`
but in my case it's doesn't work

Comment: any solutions??

Comment: I found this: https://toddmotto.com/dynamic-controllers-in-directives-with-the-undocumented-name-property/